# Mautic: How to tag users via a landing page?

Tags: mautic

I have created a campaign form in Mautic and used the manual copy feature to integrate it into my HTML landing page (this is a landing page I have made in HTML. It is not a Mautic landing page).

In Mautic, users are saved as a "contact". The contact has a field called "tags".

I would like to make use of the Mautic Tracking Javascript so I can send a value to this tag field from my HTML landing page.

Here is my code:

```
< script >
    (function(w, d, t, u, n, a, m) {
        w['MauticTrackingObject'] = n;
        w[n] = w[n] || function() {
                (w[n].q = w[n].q || []).push(arguments)
            }, a = d.createElement(t),
            m = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
        a.async = 1;
        a.src = u;
        m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
    })(window, document, 'script', 'http://newsletter.smile.ws/mtc.js', 'mt');
mt('send', 'pageview', {
    'tags': 'sunshine-book'
});
< /script>
```

To test it out, I submitted a test contact on my HTML landing page.

When I log-into Mautic and go to the contact page for the contact, the tag field is blank:

[image: Contact field]

However, the tag does appear as an option in the tag menu:

[image: tagmenu]

How can I make it so the tag field is automatically filled with the tag?

The user renzof of the Mautic forum [tested my code](https://forum.mautic.org/t/how-to-tie-entered-data-from-a-form-to-a-user/13278/11) and it worked for him, but it didn’t work for me. I think I'm doing something wrong, but I can't figure it. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the use of Http. The landing page uses https, but the code was using http (the `s` is missing), which is why it doesn't work. I updated all my code to use https and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

there is actually nothing wrong with your code, I tested it and the only problem was browser blocking the request due to cors origin, other than that it worked fine.

But I have a hunch in case it doesn't work, i noticed the tags is actually plural and in mautic contact form it taken as array, so if cross domain issue isn't there at your end, can you try tags[] instead tags. However i think normal way should have worked.